# Confusion with the equity option skew

Tags: options, equities, volatility-skew

In general out of the money (OTM) equity options have higher implied volatility (IV) than at the money (ATM) options. So assuming we have two put options (5% OTM and 10% OTM). Skew reveals that 10% OTM will have higher IV i.e. more expensive. If that be the case why would one not buy 5% OTM option instead for less + get higher protection?! am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean with 'less'? The 5% OTM put is in terms of option premium more expensive than the 10% OTM. Otherwise there would be arbitrage.

Comment: 5% OTM option is priced higher in dollar terms, lower in IV terms compared to the other and vice versa.

Comment: question is if the IV is calc'd back from dollar premium shouldn't higher dollar value for 5% OTM result in higher implied value (compared to 10% OTM)?

Answer (score 3):

It’s relatively more expensive compared to the BS price with flat volatility. The option premium of the 5% OTM put is higher than the 10% OTM put.

Comment: thanks, still confused -  isn't IV calculated back from the market premium? so if that be the case shouldn't higher option premium of 5% OTM result in higher implied vols for that option? (contrary to what skew implies)?

Comment: IV calculation takes into account $K$, which is different for the two options, not only $p$.

Comment: yes agree, but if the market convention is to define richness (or cheapness) of options using their IVs. wouldn't that imply that 10% OTM is richer than 5% OTM as its IV is higher? (although its over way around if you look at the dollar value)

Comment: Put it this way; if both options had the same IV, would you expect them to have the same price?

Comment: yeh I get the point now!